# sql oracle goup by on dates with possibilities of null values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table with `emplid` and `end_date` columns. I want from all emplids the max end_dates. If at least one end_date is null, I want to have the null value as max. So in this example:

```
emplid    end_date
1         05/04/2019
1         05/10/2019
1         null
2         05/04/2019
2         05/10/2019
```

I want as result:

```
emplid    end_date
1         null
2         05/10/2019
```

I tried something like

```
select emplid, 
       CASE 
          WHEN MAX(NVL(end_Date,'01/01/3000'))='01/01/3000' THEN null 
          ELSE end_date 
        END as end_dt 
from people 
group by emplid
```

then I get a group-by error.

Maybe it is very easy, but I don't figure out how to get properly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

```
with s(id, dt) as (
select 1, to_date('05/04/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 1, to_date('05/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 1, null                                from dual union all
select 2, to_date('05/04/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 2, to_date('05/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual)
select id, decode(count(dt), count(*), max(dt)) max_dt
from s
group by id;

        ID MAX_DT                       
---------- -----------------------------
         1                              
         2 2019-10-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do:

```
select emplid,
       (case when count(*) = count(end_date)
             then max(end_date)
        end) as max_end_date
from t
group by emplid;
```

There is no reason to introduce a "magic" maximum value (even if it is correct).

The first expression in the `case` is simply asking "do the number of non-`NULL` `end-date` values match the number of rows".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    EMPLID,
    CASE WHEN END_DATE='01/01/3000' THEN NULL ELSE END_DATE END AS END_DT
FROM
    (
        SELECT EMPLID, MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE FROM 
            (
                SELECT EMPLID, NVL(END_DATE,'01/01/3000') AS END_DATE FROM PEOPLE
            )
        GROUP BY EMPLID
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Case does not go with group by , you have to get the max value using group by first then evaluate the null values. Try below.

```
select empid, CASE WHEN NVL(eDate,'01-DEC-3000')='01-DEC-3000' THEN null ELSE edate end  end_dt  from (
select empid, MAX(NVL(eDate,'01-DEC-3000')) eDate
from 
(select 1 empid, sysdate-100 edate from dual union all
select 1 empid, sysdate-10 edate from dual union all
select 1 empid, null edate from dual union all
select 2 empid, sysdate-105 edate from dual union all
select 2 empid, sysdate-1 edate from dual ) datad
group by empid);
```